# Angular ui.router - Use resolve value in root child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i can't get this structure to work! 
I am trying to resolve my sidebarActions when the parent root state is called so the value can be used in all root.child states.

When i use root as a parent i don't get a view, tried to read about ui.router but i cant figure out what i am doing wrong. There is a ui-view="" specified in my layout & i can display home state if i remove root.

**I also want to ask** if i am planing this right? My goal is to fill out data for the sidebar based on state and IF the state has a sidebar view.

```
app.config([
            '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                // For any unmatched url, redirect to root
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

                $stateProvider
                    .state('root', {
                        url: '',
                        'abstract': true,
                        resolve: {
                            // Will resolve som data here for the child views.
                            sideBarActions: function () {
                                return { value: 'simple!' };
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .state('root.home', {
                        url: '/',
                        templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/home/home.cshtml',
                        controller: 'app.controllers.views.home', // sideBarActions is injected in controller
                    });
            }
        ]);
```

**EDIT CREATED A PLUNKR:**

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HQzgMMDawzI6M9piVV0q?p=preview)

This is how far i am, i have created the routes so they work. But i still want to solve the problem where im not doing this DRY.

Can i create this without repeating the sidebar all the time? and inject the resolved data inside the controller if the view should have a sidebar?

Comment: Can you paste the error you are getting

Comment: @DeepakN ofc, updating post.

Comment: The error wasn't clear enough to understand which variable caused this issue. Can you check if you have included `ui-router.js` in your main html and you have added `ui.router` module as dependency in your module definition.

Comment: @DeepakN There was an error when i inserted my script file, thank you for that! But my problem still persists, updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did updated your plunker a bit [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQM2pNaepdmReGoCzGVj?p=preview). Firstly the *left* and *main* areas are moved into `root` state - which is still abstract.

There are two substates `home` and `customers`... for which also generated navigation on the left, basd on the rosolved **sideBarActions**. Finally, there is a `customer` detail, substate of `customers`.

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '',
      'abstract': true,
      resolve: {
        sideBarActions: function() {
          return {
            actionNames: ['root.home','root.customers']
          };
        }
      },
      views: {
        '': { templateUrl: 'tpl.layout.html',},
        'sidebar@root': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.actionBar.html',
          controller: 'actionBarCtrl',
        }
      }
    })
    .state('root.home', {
      url: '/',
      template: '<div>root.home content</div>',
    })
    .state('root.customers', {
      url: '/customers',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.customers.html',
    })
    .state('root.customers.customer', {
      url: '/:customerId',
      template: '<div>customer with {{id}}</div>',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams) 
                  {$scope.id = $stateParams.customerId},
    })
```

The only place where we can see absolute naming is in the root state definition, where we introduce the template, and do inject into there as well `'sidebar@root': {...}`

That all should show how the ui-router **multi-views** and **nested-states** could bring us lot of profit. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQM2pNaepdmReGoCzGVj?p=preview)